# How does one make a question go 'viral'

Tags: discussion, questions, best-practices

Some questions get tremendous amounts of views in a short time, such as [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/496139/something-is-burning-in-the-server-room-how-can-i-quickly-identify-what-it-is) which got 36k views in the first day, but the questions before and after it (that weren't closed) didn't even squeak 100 (like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/496109/roll-back-suspended-msi-install-from-command-line)). Asking a good question (a 'stumper' or canonical question) would probably play a part, and possibly the tags even though my example question only had a single tag which currently has 36 subscribers.

Generating this type of viewing on other questions could be beneficial in general.

Comment: the [tweet](https://twitter.com/ServerFault/status/319982734565068800) had something to do with the number of views, but no idea how the system decides what to tweet.

Comment: Sorry I noticed that on the first day too, forgot to add that in my question. that is a good one.

Comment: The question had a funny title while still being a real/serious question.  Please don't spend your time trying to reproduce that.

Comment: @djechlin the theory is that the more people who view a question the better chances of a quality answer, that's all.

Comment: @MDMoore313 that question has lots of flame wars and trolling on it and is locked to prevent further answers, and therefore a chance of a new good answer coming.  Too much attention is not good.

Comment: From what I've seen, questions that go viral and are not of the "fun" type are almost always well-answered *before* they went viral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tweeting interesting questions to your horde of followers is one way to get lots of eyeballs. Linking to questions on your popular blog, etc., are similarly useful.

It looks like the question you linked was tweeted pretty early on.

Writing a decent question with an intriguing title helps, of course, but there's no formula for setting a question on fire.